# How can I only allow a player to spawn once on a Minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'd like to have a Minecraft server where a user can only spawn once and when they die they get booted from the server. I know I can use white-list.txt to only allow a specific user on at a time, but I'm unsure how to detect that a user has died and drop their connection. How would you go about doing this?

Comment: Are you seriously looking to create a **Hardcore Server** for *Minecraft*!?

Comment: @LessPop - There are already plenty of Hardcore MC servers out there, just Google it.

Comment: @Less: He might be playing a variation of the [Hunger Games](http://i.imgur.com/4wXV7.jpg).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With this plugin for bukkit -> [Exile v2.0 - Banish from the server or world on death!](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/rpg-exile-v2-0-banish-from-the-server-or-world-on-death-revived-1000.29041/)

You can set a timer on how long they can be banned before they can come back to the server or set it to eternity.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test this, but I'll accept it since it's the only answer after a couple days, and it's highly rated. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7):

You can do this in a vanilla server now by setting this line in `server.properties`:

```
hardcore=true
```

This will auto-ban anyone who dies on the server.